# Limit not working on count distinct? mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this to count how many messages an user has:

```
SELECT count(distinct `from`) FROM chat WHERE `to`=? and recd='0' limit 100
```

it is retorning 120.418. The limit 100 is not working. any ideas?

if an user has more than 100 messages I'd like to count only 100.

Comment: I I am just wondering how you get results at all since `from` and `to` are mySQL reserved keywords

Comment: using the ``` it works fine.

Comment: Ah!! okay.. thanks... now you solved my problem :) but sorry I can't solve yours

Comment: In you query you are just select one rows ..not 100 .. the result is the total  for distinct from

Answer (score 3):

Here the way to go... You need 2 Selects

```
 SELECT COUNT( A.`from` ) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT `from` FROM chat WHERE `to`=? and recd='0' limit 100 ) A
```

Sorry, it was not tested. Now its working

Comment: it shows a sintaxe error, maybe something missing? :/

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT `from` FROM chat WHERE `to`= ? and recd=0 LIMIT 100) t works nice! thanks.